# dotnet command doesn't work from powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, windows-10

When I type `dotnet` from Powershell in Windows 10 I am prompted with a window to choose an application to open "that" file. (How do you want to open this file?).
From cmd it works fine, but not from Powershell (or even from VSCode Terminal.
Any ideas?

[image: Application selection dialog]

Comment: Did you install .NET Sdk?

Comment: is it in envirment variables? PATH?

Comment: Can you show us the output from `Get-Command dotnet |Format-List`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen 
Name            : dotnet
CommandType     : Application
Definition      : C:\WINDOWS\system32\dotnet
Extension       :
Path            : C:\WINDOWS\system32\dotnet
FileVersionInfo : File:             C:\WINDOWS\system32\dotnet
                  InternalName:
                  OriginalFilename:
                  FileVersion:
                  FileDescription:
                  Product:
                  ProductVersion:
                  Debug:            False
                  Patched:          False
                  PreRelease:       False

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan yes, I have the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\" there in the Path from System variables.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks, you nailed it. There was an empty file called "dotnet" in my system32 folder..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running this command `Get-Command dotnet |Format-List` in powershell I realised there was an empty file called `dotnet` in my C:\WINDOWS\system32\ folder. I don't know how that got there honestly...

**Before the fix**

[image: Get-Command dotnet]

**After the fix**
[image: Fixed]

Comment: If dotnet is not a powershell command, how does powershell know what to do with it? Is dotnet in powershell an alisa?